# limit the number of log files using log4j2 RollingFileAppender

Tags: log4j, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I'm trying to limit the number of log files i maintain, using MaxBackupIndex but fail to achieve that. this is my log4j2.xml, i expected to log to a different log file every second but to rotate only between 2 files and not create more than that (or delete older ones):

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="OGBackend" packages="">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">C:/logs/</Property>
    </Properties>
    <Parameters>
        <param name="MaxBackupIndex" value="2"/>
    </Parameters>
    <Appenders>
        <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="${log-path}/myexample.log"
                     filePattern="${log-path}/myexample-%d{yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss}-%i.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <pattern>%d{dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}- %c{1}: %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="2"/>

        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="root" level="debug" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile" level="debug"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="debug" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

any advice?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no official support for that sadly. What the max backup index(used with the %i lookup in file pattern) does is prevent more than 2 files per second rather than 2 files total.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-524

A link to a feature request about the same issue.